# Como obter posição do RecycleView invertido?

Tags: android

Eu to com um recycleview q pega os dados de um banco de dados ( estou usando Sugar ORM ) e inverti a ordem pois queria dos mais novos pra os mais velhos, porem para deletar eu preciso da posição no banco de dados, porem eu to fazendo com swipe, e ele pega a posição do adpater ( que não é a mesma do DB porque esta invertido ), como conseguir a posição assim ?

```
  List<Notificacao> listnotificacoes = Notificacao.listAll(Notificacao.class);

        Log.d("igr","Lista de Notificaoes: " + listnotificacoes);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        llm.setReverseLayout(true);
        llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        mAdapterNoti = new AdapterNotificacao(listnotificacoes);
        mrecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterNoti);

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d("igr","posicao"+position);
                int posicaodb = position+1;
                Log.d("igr","posicaodb"+posicaodb);
                try{
                    try{
                        Notificacao notificacao = Notificacao.findById(Notificacao.class,posicaodb);
                        Log.d("igr",""+notificacao.getMensagem());
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("igr","erro ao obter mensagem da notificao" + e);
                    }
                    //notificacao.delete();
                    //Log.d("igr","deletou  a notificao no BD");
                    //mAdapterNoti.notifyItemRemoved(position);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("igr","Erro ao deletar a notificacao no DB" + e);

                }

            }
        };
```

Código proposto pelo márcio:

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
    final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    Log.d("igr","posicao"+position);
    int positionToDelete = mAdapterNoti.getItemCount() - position - 1;
    //int posicaodb = position+1;
    Log.d("igr","positionToDelete"+positionToDelete);
    try{
        try{
            Notificacao notificacao = Notificacao.findById(Notificacao.class,positionToDelete);
            Log.d("igr",""+notificacao.getMensagem());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("igr","erro ao obter mensagem da notificao" + e);
        }
        //notificacao.delete();
        //Log.d("igr","deletou  a notificao no BD");
        //mAdapterNoti.notifyItemRemoved(position);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("igr","Erro ao deletar a notificacao no DB" + e);

    }

}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir a posição para deletar no banco dessa forma:

```
int positionToDelete = adapterSize - adapterPosition;
// supondo que o índice do primeiro registro é 1, conforme documentação do Sugar.
```

onde adapterSize é o total de itens do Adapter (RecyclerView) e adapterPosition é a posição do item da RecyclerView que você está fazendo o swipe.

Se não quiser fazer nenhuma matemática, pode criar um método auxiliar no Adapter que retorna o id do item numa determinada posição e chamar esse método no onSwiped() para deletar o item pelo id.

Comment: tentei aqui e não funcionou @Márcio, adicionei seu código na pergunta, veja se apliquei corretamente

Comment: Mas dá algum erro? O que exatamente não funcionou?

Comment: Posição do getadapterposition: 10 ( primeiro item de cima pra baixo eu fiz o swipe )
Posição pra deletar : 0
Erro: "Erro ao deletar a notificacao no DB: java.lang.NullPointerException
Pensei que poderia ser pq o banco começa no 1, porem adicionei + 1 na conta mas mesmo assim da erro

Comment: Pelo erro, o seu método Notificacao.findById() está retornando null. Tem que entender porque. Se puder, posta ele lá em cima.

Comment: É um método padrão do sugar ORM, mas vou verificar isso, to pensando em trocar de banco de dados

Comment: Refiz o banco mas mesmo assim, dando o mesmo erro, eu mando ele deletar a primeira de cima pra baixo que é a notificação 5, mas o valor passado pelo seu código é o primeiro de baixo pra cima.

Comment: LOG: 07-05 22:54:00.277 10904-10904/br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal D/igr: posicao: 1
07-05 22:54:00.277 10904-10904/br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal D/igr: positionToDelete: 0
07-05 22:54:00.277 10904-10904/br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal D/SQL Log: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM NOTIFICACAO WHERE id=? LIMIT 1
07-05 22:54:00.277 10904-10904/br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal D/igr: Erro ao deletar a notificacao no DBjava.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Debugando aqui percebi, que ele ta passando null mesmo, n to entendendo o porque

Comment: Pelo que vi da documentação desse Sugar, o primeiro índice do BD é 1, e não 0, então tem que tirar o -1 da minha resposta. Vou editar.

Comment: Poisé notei tb o -1, tinha testado sem ele, e mesmo assim mesma coisa

Comment: Como comentei na sua outra pergunta, tente implementar a base usando as classes nativas: SQLiteOpenHelper e SQLiteDatabase